# Two grouping select method by using mysql, which is faster and which is better?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

there are 40,000 records in a table, I want to devide to 4 group.
first way:

```
  def prepare_params(div, mod)
    results = []
    Account.find_each do |account|
      next unless account.id % div == mod
      results << [account.id, account.name]
    end
    results
  end
```

secord way:

```
  def prepare_params(block, block_size)
    results = Account.limit(block_size).offset(block_size * (block - 1)).pluck(:id, :name)
  end
```

This two grouping select method by using mysql, which is faster and which is better?

Comment: [`require 'benchmark'`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html). BTW, the second is definitely better since it does not iterates 40K records inside ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second will be much faster and better, because It provide model job to the database.

In the first you do the DB job manually, without indexes and use unspecialized algorithms for it.

Of course, if it is 1-time task there is no a lot of difference. Bun, if it is regular task you can see speed improvement by your eyes, not only by synthetic tests.

Also, I should mention, that algorithms will provide different division of your data. first one will divide like `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4...`, and tha second will provide `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1....` where numbers is the columns, keep in mind it also.